# Does the new 'dynamic' C# 4.0 keyword deprecate the 'var' keyword?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic-languages

When C# 4.0 comes out and we have the dynamic keyword as described in this [excellent presentation by Anders Hejlsberg](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/), (C# is evolving faster than I can keep up.. I didn't have much time to acquaint myself with the var keyword)

Would I still need the var keyword ? Is there anything that var can do.. that dynamic can't?

```
var x = SomeFunctionThatIKnowReturnsSomeKindOfList();
// do something with x

dynamic x = SomeFunctionThatIKnowReturnsSomeKindOfList();
// do something with x
```

Comment: Maybe not important, but while var is a keyword, dynamic is not. It's a type.

Comment: So it 'dynamic' basically like declaring something of type "object" but the compiler does not complain, when you call methods on it that do not exist?

Comment: Yes it will be resolved at run-time. If it exists, the method will be called.. if not Boom!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

No, they're very different.

`var` means "infer the type of the variable at compile-time" - but it's still entirely statically bound.

`dynamic` means "assume I can do anything I want with this variable" - i.e. the compiler doesn't know what operations are available, and the DLR will work out what the calls *really* mean at execution time.

I expect to use `dynamic` very rarely - only when I truly want dynamic behaviour:

- `var` lets you catch typos etc at compile-time
- statically bound code is always going to run faster than dynamically bound code (even if the difference becomes reasonably small)
- statically bound code gives more compile-time support beyond just errors: you can find call hierarchies, refactoring will work better, Intellisense is available etc

Comment: That was my missing piece.. var is static-binding (and hence comes with the benefits of compile-time checks, tooling, etc.)

Comment: you can basically think of var as some syntactic sugar

Answer (score 17):

Dynamic and var represent two completely different ideas.

**var**

Var essentially asks the compiler to figure out the type of the variable based on the expression on the right hand side of the assignment statement.  The variable is then treated exactly as if it were explicitly declared as the type of the expression.  For example the following two statements are equivalent

```
var a = "foo";
string a = "foo";
```

The key to take away here is that "var" is 100% type safe and is a compile time operation

**dynamic**

Dynamic is in many ways the exact opposite of var.  Using dynamic is essentially eliminating all type safety for thet particular variable.  It many ways it has no type.  When you call a method or field on the variable, the determination on how to invoke that field occurs at runtime.  For example

```
dynamic d = SomeOperation();
d.Foo(); // Will this fail or not?  Won't know until you run the program
```

The key to take away here is that "dynamic" is not type safe and is a runtime operation

Comment: It's still type safe, its just that the type isn't known at compile time. If the actual (runtime) object doesn't have a particular member you're trying to access, you'll get exception.

Comment: Compare: you can use var in .NET 2.0 Projects. Not dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will still need var:

**Var** is a *variable* whose type will be inferred by the compiler.

**dynamic** will have its type assigned at runtime

So:

```
Var i = "Hello World"
```

will have its type inferred as a string type in doing so intellisence will give you all the methods that string can use like,

```
i.Split("/")
```

Where as:

```
dynamic i = "Hello World"
```

won't have its type inferred untill runtime because the complier dosn't know what type it is yet, but will still let you do:

```
i.Split("/")
```

but when it calls the method that you need it may fail because the type is wrong and the method isn't there.

Comment: Pedant: "var" is a *variable* whose type will be inferred by the compiler. The object is unaffected. "dynamic" is a variable that is statically typed as "dynamic" - it is the dispatch mechanism that changes (the variable is still typed as "dynamic").